# iOS ABAddressBook How to change existing phone number?

Tags: ios, swift, abaddressbook

I want to check if contact exists and change its phone number if it does.

I tried to do so and got `exc_bad_access` in the last line of code:

```
if doesPersonExistWithFirstName(firstName: "Call Recorder", inAddressBook: adbk)
        {
            let existingContact: ABRecord! = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(adbk, recordID).takeRetainedValue()
            var success: Bool = false
            let phoneNumbers: ABMutableMultiValue = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(ABPropertyType(kABMultiStringPropertyType)).takeRetainedValue()
            var error: Unmanaged<CFError>? = nil

            success = ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(phoneNumbers, recordServicePhoneNumber!, kABPersonPhoneMainLabel, nil)
            print("setting phone number successful? \(success)")
            success = ABRecordSetValue(existingContact, kABPersonPhoneProperty, phoneNumbers, &error)
            print("adding phone numbers successful? \(success)")

            success = ABAddressBookAddRecord(adbk, existingContact, &error)
            print("Adbk addRecord successful? \(success)")
            success = ABAddressBookSave(adbk, &error)
            print("Adbk Save successful? \(success)")
        }
        else
        {
            let newContact: ABRecord! = ABPersonCreate().takeRetainedValue()
            var success: Bool = false
            let newFirstName: NSString = "Call Recorder"
            let image: UIImage = UIImage(named: "record")!
            let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
            let phoneNumbers: ABMutableMultiValue = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(ABPropertyType(kABMultiStringPropertyType)).takeRetainedValue()
            var error: Unmanaged<CFError>? = nil

            success = ABRecordSetValue(newContact, kABPersonFirstNameProperty, newFirstName as CFTypeRef, &error)
            print("setting first name was successful? \(success)")
            success = ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(phoneNumbers, recordServicePhoneNumber!, kABPersonPhoneMainLabel, nil)
            print("setting phone number successful? \(success)")
            success = ABPersonSetImageData(newContact, imageData as CFData!, &error)
            print("setting image successful? \(success)")
            success = ABRecordSetValue(newContact, kABPersonPhoneProperty, phoneNumbers, &error)
            print("adding phone numbers successful? \(success)")
            success = ABAddressBookAddRecord(adbk, newContact, &error)
            print("Adbk addRecord successful? \(success)")
            success = ABAddressBookSave(adbk, &error)
            print("Adbk Save successful? \(success)")
        }
    } **// I get exception here**
```

Code works, phone number changes correctly, but app crashes every time I run it.

**UPD:** I've ran zombies instrument and it gave me this:

```
An Objective-C message was sent to a deallocated 'CPRecord' object (zombie) at address: 0x7c6a3200.
```

**UPD2:** I found out this line crashes app:

```
let existingContact: ABRecord! = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(adbk, recordID).takeRetainedValue()
```

What can be the problem?

Comment: What is the error you are getting in debug area ?

Comment: There are no errors in debug area

Comment: Add availability check before getting result, ABRecord is deprecated in ios9  and CPRecord is available now for swift.
This is what zombie is saying that you are receiving CPRecord as ABRecord. Kindly check this, may it will help you. Also by adding availability you can test if this code works for your existing iOS or not. :)

Comment: I added availability check as you said, app still crashes :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in this line as I thought:

```
let existingContact: ABRecord! = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(adbk, recordID).takeRetainedValue()
```

I changed my function so now it uses `ABRecord` instead of `ABRecordID` to access required record.

Fixed code:

```
if doesPersonExistWithFirstName(firstName: "Call Recorder", inAddressBook: adbk)
        {
            var success: Bool = false
            let phoneNumbers: ABMutableMultiValue = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(ABPropertyType(kABMultiStringPropertyType)).takeRetainedValue()
            var error: Unmanaged<CFError>? = nil

            success = ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(phoneNumbers, recordServicePhoneNumber!, kABPersonPhoneMainLabel, nil)
            print("setting phone number successful? \(success)")
            success = ABRecordSetValue(existingContact, kABPersonPhoneProperty, phoneNumbers, &error)
            print("adding phone numbers successful? \(success)")
            success = ABAddressBookAddRecord(adbk, existingContact, &error)
            print("Adbk addRecord successful? \(success)")
            success = ABAddressBookSave(adbk, &error)
            print("Adbk Save successful? \(success)")
        }
        else
        {
            let newContact: ABRecord! = ABPersonCreate().takeRetainedValue()
            var success: Bool = false
            let newFirstName: NSString = "Call Recorder"
            let image: UIImage = UIImage(named: "record")!
            let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
            let phoneNumbers: ABMutableMultiValue = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(ABPropertyType(kABMultiStringPropertyType)).takeRetainedValue()
            var error: Unmanaged<CFError>? = nil

            success = ABRecordSetValue(newContact, kABPersonFirstNameProperty, newFirstName as CFTypeRef, &error)
            print("setting first name was successful? \(success)")
            success = ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(phoneNumbers, recordServicePhoneNumber!, kABPersonPhoneMainLabel, nil)
            print("setting phone number successful? \(success)")
            success = ABPersonSetImageData(newContact, imageData as CFData!, &error)
            print("setting image successful? \(success)")
            success = ABRecordSetValue(newContact, kABPersonPhoneProperty, phoneNumbers, &error)
            print("adding phone numbers successful? \(success)")
            success = ABAddressBookAddRecord(adbk, newContact, &error)
            print("Adbk addRecord successful? \(success)")
            success = ABAddressBookSave(adbk, &error)
            print("Adbk Save successful? \(success)")
        }
```

`existingContacts` implementation:

```
var existingContact: ABRecord! = ABPersonCreate().takeRetainedValue()
func doesPersonExistWithFirstName(firstName paramFirstName: String,
                                      inAddressBook addressBook: ABAddressBook) -> Bool
    {
        let people = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook).takeRetainedValue() as NSArray as [ABRecord]
        for person: ABRecord in people
        {
            let firstName = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty).takeRetainedValue() as! String
            if firstName == paramFirstName
            {
                existingContact = person
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
```